# C++ error: expected type specifier before "class name"

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error? I did specify the type for my node and for my class.

Not quite sure what is going on. For both the StackLL and the Node class, I specify .

.h file

```
using namespace std;




template<class Type>
class Node {

    public:
        Node(Type _data);
        Type data;
        Node* next;


};


template <class Type>
class StackLL {

    public:

        StackLL(); //constructor
        ~StackLL();

        void pop();
        void push(Type _data);
        int size();
        bool empty();

        int lSize;
        Node<Type>* top;


};
```

.cpp file

```
#include<iostream>
#include "stack.h"

using namespace std;



template <class Type>
Node<Type>::Node(Type _data) {

    data = _data;
    next = NULL;

};



template <class Type>
StackLL<Type>::StackLL() {

    lSize = 0;
    top = NULL;
};


template <class Type>
StackLL<Type>::~StackLL() {

    delete top;

};


template <class Type>
void StackLL<Type>::push(Type _data) {

    Node<Type>* temp = new Node(_data)

    lSize++;

    if (top == NULL) {
        top = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = top;
        top = temp;
    };

};


template <class Type>
void StackLL<Type>::pop() {

    if (top == NULL) {

        cout << "Empty";

    } else {

        Node<Type>* temp = top;

        top = top->next;

        temp->next = NULL;

        free(temp);

        lSize--;

    };

};


template <class Type>
int StackLL<Type>::size() {

    return lSize;

};



template <class Type>
bool StackLL<Type>::empty() {

    if (lSize == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

The error is occurring for my stackLL push function, here:

```
template <class Type>
void StackLL<Type>::push(Type _data) {

    Node<Type>* temp = new Node(Type _data)

    lSize++;

    if (top == NULL) {
        top = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = top;
        top = temp;
    };

};
```

For this line: `Node<Type>* temp = new Node(Type _data)` the compiler is telling me "expected type specifier before "Node"

Any ideas? Thanks!

EDIT: changed this part

`Node<Type>* temp = new Node(Type _data)` to `Node<Type>* temp = new Node(_data)` but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Does `Node<Type>* temp = new Node<Type>(Type _data)` work?

Comment: @ProxicT, wow I feel stupid. Thanks so much. Yes it worked......I even searched this on stackoverflow and for other people, it seemed they didn't do that when using new. Also, I tried it earlier, but the reason it failed was because in my input parameters I had Type _data when it should just be _data. Thanks so much!

Comment: You don't have to feel stupid, these silly mistakes happen to all of us :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've only specified the type for the pointer type, but forgot to specify it on the right hand side where the instance is actually created.

To fix it, specify the type of the `Node` where the instance is created:

```
Node<Type>* temp = new Node<Type>(_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Node` is a templated type, but it is not a nested type of the `StackLL` templated class, so a Node's `Type` parameter cannot be deduced automatically inside of `StackLL`'s method bodies.  You need to explicitly include the `Type` parameter whenever you refer to the `Node` class.  You are doing that in the declaration of the `temp` variable, but not in the `new` statement.

Also, you are specifying `Type` in the argument list when passing `_data` to the `Node` constructor. Don't do that. You specify types when declaring variables and parameters, not when assigning values to them.

IOW, you need to change this line:

```
Node<Type>* temp = new Node(Type _data);
```

To this instead:

```
Node<Type>* temp = new Node<Type>(_data);
```

---

On a separate note:

You will eventually run into problems trying to separate a templated class into `.h` and `.cpp` files as you have demonstrated. See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/) for details.

Also, your `.h` file appears to lack any kind of header guard to protect against its declarations being `#include`'d multiple times in the same translation file (`.cpp`), eg:

```cpp
#ifndef StackH
#define StackH

// Node and StackLL declarations here...

#endif
```

Or

```cpp
#pragma once

// Node and StackLL declarations here...
```

Depending on which compiler you are using.